# What is the right way to add PHP code to a certain part of a page

Tags: php

I know I can add PHP to the functions file.  And I know I can make a plugin.

I basically need to make a calculator of sorts and send the values to an email signup.

What is the best way to achieve this.  I think a plugin, but then how would I position the plugin at a place on an already existing page?

Sorry if this is a noob question, I really want to understand the correct way to achieve this before starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin is just a file that gets loaded into WordPress, it doesn't have a *location* on the page. In fact WordPress doesn't know which page it is yet when  plugins are loaded. It may not even be a frontend page!

So if a plugin is just a place to put code such as hooks and filters, how do you embed code in a page?

There are several methods:

- blocks
- shortcodes
- widgets
- theme template files

You  can register blocks/shortcodes/widgets in a plugin, whereas templates files are theme specific.

I recommend searching the site for how to create and use a shortcode, this will be the easiest option for you at the moment.

Comment: Perfect, I can do that, I think I have done that in the past.  I'll just do that in the function file.